# Sharing an Eclipse Perspective

Tags: eclipse, perspective

I have created an Eclipse Python perspective to suit what I need, and have deleted most of the menus and toolbar icons. I want to keep it this way. However, the goal of this perspective is to be used by others, so I want to share it as it is exactly.

I've tried multiple methods, File>Export>General>Preferences, using the Yatta Profiles tool, and others, none of it worked (Yatta Profiles works fine, using in my own computer, but on another computer, all the default menus are back).

Does anyone have a solution for this, where one can share an Eclipse perspective EXACTLY as it is?

Comment: Your question has little to do with Python programming and instead is about using a particular IDE — so I would suggest asking on [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @martineau Since the Eclipse IDE is a [software tool commonly used by programmers, it's an on-topic question for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). So this question is better asked here than on Super User. I have removed the _python_ tag since it is not a question about Python.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to create an Eclipse plug-in providing that Perspective (via https://help.eclipse.org/2020-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_perspectives.html?cp=2_1_1_196), or convince the developers of the Python plug-in you're using to provide it for you.